# ifstream No such file or directory C++

Tags: c++, file, path, ifstream

So I'm trying to write a shader class in C++ similar to [this](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders). This is my file structure:

```
| -- /source
|    | --  main.cpp
|    | -- /Shaders
|    |    | -- Shader.h
|    |    | -- shader.frag
|    |    | -- shader.vert
```

In my main.cpp file, I import shaders.h. Shaders.h constains the shader class, which reads in shader code from the shader.frag and shader.vert files (or so it should). The path I pass from main.cpp is `Shaders/shader.frag` and `Shaders/shader.vert`, and I am getting the error `No such file or directory`.

Here is my (or their) relevant shader code:

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
Shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath)
    {
        // 1. retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        // ensure ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            // open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath); <------- this is where it is getting caught
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath); <---------- and i assume it would be here as well
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;

            // read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();

            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();

            // convert stream into string
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            char buffer[256];
            strerror_s(buffer, 256, errno);
            printf("ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ: %s\n", buffer);
        }
...
```

I have tried multiple different path variations. I've tried passing an absolute path as well, and consistently get the same error. I would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: is that txt file or json file?@Saucy Dumpling

Comment: it's just a text file. Do you think I should try renaming to a .txt?

Comment: while opening in code you mention .txt  (i.e) vShaderFile.open("FILENAME.txt");, but make sure file present inside folder is txt dont rename it . But the file should be present in the same folder where source code exist

Comment: I doubt that the file suffix is your problem. You can read text files with whatever suffix you give it. If you use an IDE (e.g. VisualStudio) the binaries may be compiled into a separate folder. So, when the application is started the current directory isn't the source folder but the one the binaries are in (by default). Either use an absolute file path or adjust the current directory for the started application. In VisualStudio, there is a setting (under Debugging of main project) but other IDEs surely provide it as well.

Comment: A very simple check you can do: Write to a new file from your function `std::ofstream ct; ct.open("bla.txt"); ct << "klaf";` then go look in the source tree where the new file shows up. That should tell you where the directory root is.

Comment: Windows expect double slash in file path like c:\\Data\\shader.vert. check if this kind of problem is there

Comment: I have tried absolute paths with double \\, and that also did not work. I may try creating a file once I get home from work (this is a personal project).

Comment: Frodyne, I did your print thing and found it was a level above where I thought, so I just had to add `./source/` to the path and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the `<fstream>` library.

Comment: The fstream library is actually included, I just did not show that in my example code. I will update the question to show the includes as well.